# Calculating $\int \sqrt{1 + x^{-2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

I would like to find

$$\int \sqrt{1 + x^{-2}}dx$$

I have found that it is equivalent to
$$
\int \frac{\sqrt{1 + x^2}}{x}dx
$$
but I am not sure what to do about it. With trig substitution $x = \tan(x)$ I get
$$
\int \frac{1}{\sin(\theta)\cos^2(\theta)}d\theta
$$
but that seems to be a dead end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\int \frac{1}{\sin(\theta)\cos^2(\theta)}d\theta
$$
$$
=\int \frac{\sin(\theta)}{\cos^2(\theta)(1-\cos^2(\theta))}d\theta
$$
then use $u=\cos(\theta)$ and partial fractions on the result.

Answer (score 4):

Let $x^2+1=u^2$, so that $2x\,dx=2u\,du$, which implies

$${dx\over x}={u\,du\over x^2}={u\over u^2-1}du$$

Then

$$\int{\sqrt{1+x^2}\over x}dx=\int{u^2\over u^2-1}du={1\over2}\int\left(2+{1\over u-1}-{1\over u+1} \right)du=u+{1\over2}\ln\left(u-1\over u+1 \right)+C\\=\sqrt{x^2+1}+{1\over2}\ln\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}-1\over\sqrt{x^2+1}+1 \right)+C$$

Answer (score 2):

and
$$
\int \frac{1}{\sin(\theta)\cos^2(\theta)}d\theta=
\int \frac{\sin\theta}{\sin^2(\theta)\cos^2(\theta)}d\theta=
\int \frac{-d(\cos\theta)}{(1-\cos^2\theta)\cos^2(\theta)}d\theta=...
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\int \sqrt{1 + x^{-2}}dx=\int \frac{\sqrt{1 + x^2}}{x}dx$$

With substitution $u=x^{2}$, $du=2xdx$.

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{1 + x^2}}{x}dx=\int \frac{\sqrt{u+1}}{2u}du=\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{\sqrt{u+1}}{u}du $$

With substitution $v=\sqrt{u+1}$, $dv=\frac{1}{2v}du$.

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{u+1}{u}du
&=\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{2v^{2}}{v^{2}-1}dv\\[6px]
&=v-\operatorname{arctanh} (v)+C\\[6px]
&=\sqrt{x^{2}+1}-\operatorname{arctanh}(\sqrt{x^{2}+1})+C.
\end{align}

Comment: Upon your first suggested substitution, $$dx= \frac{du}{2x} = \frac{du}{2\sqrt u} $$ $$\int \frac{\sqrt{1 + x^2}}{x}dx=\int \frac{\sqrt{u+1}}{2\sqrt u}du$$

Answer (score 2):

I get $\int \frac{sec \theta}{tan \theta}d \theta$ from your simplification

Which gives $\int \frac{1/cos \theta}{sin \theta / cos \theta}d \theta$

= $\int \frac{1}{sin \theta}d \theta$

= $\int csc \theta d \theta$

which integrates similarly to $sec\  \theta$

and then the fun of back-substituting.

Comment: I am not sure I see how you get the $\sec(\theta) / \tan(\theta)$

Comment: You had 
$$\int \frac{\sqrt{ 1 + x^2}}{x} dx$$

Comment: Yes, but don't you also need to do $dx = ... d\theta$?

Comment: Sorry, keep hitting return too soon. I think I had a typo there and intended to correct, sorry. My error.  Still getting used to this system.

You substituted  $x = tan(\theta)$ so $dx = sec^2 (\theta) d \theta$

$ \sqrt{1 + x^2} =  \sqrt{1 + tan^2 (\theta)} = \sqrt{sec^2(\theta} } = sec(\theta)$

You now have

$$ \int \frac{ sec \theta * sec^2 \theta} {tan \theta} d \theta $$

so yes I slipped up somewhere. Had another approach to this and lost it,

The sinh sub suggested in another answer is a good one.

Answer (score 2):

Set $x^{-1}=\sinh t$, so $\sqrt{1+x^{-2}}=\cosh t$. Then
$$
dx=-\frac{\cosh t}{\sinh^2t}\,dt
$$
and the integral becomes
$$
-\int\frac{\cosh^2t}{\sinh^2t}\,dt=
-\int\frac{1+\sinh^2t}{\sinh^2t}\,dt=\frac{\cosh t}{\sinh t}-t+c=
\sqrt{1+x^2}-\operatorname{arsinh}\frac{1}{x}+c
$$
You can find a more explicit expression for $\operatorname{arsinh}\frac{1}{x}$ by setting
$$
\frac{1}{x}=\frac{e^t-e^{-t}}{2}
$$
or
$$
xe^{2t}-2e^t-x=0
$$
so
$$
e^t=\frac{1+\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x}
$$
The final antiderivative is
$$
\sqrt{1+x^2}-\log\frac{1+\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x}+c
$$

Comment: This is very nice. I like the use of the hyperbolic functions ending with something with a log. Thanks!